# Redundant piece of information in worded function problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

[question](https://m.imgur.com/ySbsXak)

For part c) what is the point of the "g(x)=f(x)"? It didn't seem to effect the final answer (-infinite, 0] but what was its purpose, if it had one?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose your alternatively would be to just say that $f$ in invertible in $(-\infty, 0]$. The thing is $f$'s domain has already been defined as $\mathbb R$. If you change its domain, it's no longer $f$, it's something different. The question begins by giving this "different thing" in the name of $g$.